# Symfony2/Sylius don't detect stripe/stripe-php library

Tags: php, symfony, stripe-payments, sylius, payum

I'm using `Symfony 2.8` with `Sylius 0.16.0-dev` and despite of installing stripe-php library via composer `composer require stripe/stripe-php` this part of code throw an exception

```
if (!class_exists('Stripe')) {
            throw new \LogicException('You must install "stripe/stripe-php" library.');
}
```

Could you explain me why?

Comment: installation composer run correctly ? Are you sure that library is loaded ?

Comment: @darkomen  composer runs successful and everything loads in vendor folder. Symfony has autoloader which loads everything from vendor folder.

Comment: Wouldn't the class actually be `Stripe\Stripe`?

Comment: @qooplmao Maybe. I'll try in an hour. But is there any possibility to access this class like that? This is part of another library (payum) and I don't want to change its code.

Comment: If you are using version 1.1.4 of Payum there aren't a lot of changes since then to the master (https://github.com/Payum/Payum/compare/1.1.4...master). You could use the master version in place of the actual one `"payum/payum": "dev-master as 1.1.4"` until the latest version is released.

Comment: Thank you very much, @qooplmao. That was the case! Please make an answer from this comment, in order I can mark it as an correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested..

If you are using version 1.1.4 of Payum there aren't a lot of changes since then to the master (https://github.com/Payum/Payum/compare/1.1.4...master). You could use the master version in place of the actual one `"payum/payum": "dev-master as 1.1.4"` until the latest version is released.

Answer (score 1):

Add *stripe/stripe-php* in the *require-dev* section of your composer.json. Like this:

```
"require-dev": {
    ...
    "stripe/stripe-php": "~1.0"
},
```